# Multiprocessing for the recursive function value generator

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing, generator

I have a simple recursive function and a generator of its values:

```
def rec(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n + rec(n-1)

lis=[]    
for i in range(1,1000):
    lis.append(rec(i))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36,...]
```

Can multiprocessing be used in such a construction?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use such recursive function?

Comment: not exactly the same, but similar to its more complicated problem, which is not needed here because of probably intricate explanations.

Comment: Instead of going from `n` down to `1`, would it make sense to go from `1` to `n`, yielding along the way?  Your example can be done with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: Before considering multiprocessing, I would try writing a more efficient algorithm. This problem, and their ilks may have a closed form solution or solved efficiently using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe here is a *clean* [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map): you map an iterable of values to a list of values such that *x<sub>i</sub>* in the original list, is mapped on *f(x<sub>i</sub>)* in the result.

We can use it with a `Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def rec(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n + rec(n-1)

pool = Pool(4)

lis = pool.map(rec, range(1,1000))
```

Here `4` is the number of processes that process the request. Ususally this is the number or cores (or a multiple of the number of cores).

Note however that in your case, you can substitute the `rec` function with:

```
# fast implementation
def rec(n):
    return n*(n+1)//2
```

Comment: thanks. I thought that with recursive functions it will be more complicated :)